# Is Ruby Thread-Safe by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I ran following code in console for more than 10 times, and it resulted in same output, `100000`.

```
i = 0
1000.times do
Thread.start { 100.times { i += 1 } }
end
i
```

Shouldn't it give me different output, as I'm reading and updating `i`, using multiple threads. It made me wonder, is ruby actually thread-safe by default? If not, then why do I see same output always?

p.s. If you say, it is not thread-safe by default then can you share a simple example, which will give me different result when I run in rails console?

**Edit:**

In other words, is above code running 1000 threads concurrently? If yes, then result shouldn't be `100000` **ALWAYS**. If no, then how to run multiple threads concurrently?

If I add `puts`, then print order of `i` will change. It implies threads are interleaving each other, but are they running concurrently?

I'm not asking, how to make this thread-safe. I understand concepts of  `mutex`/`locking` & synchronous/asynchronous process. Because I understand them, I'm failing to understand output of this code.

Comment: What do you mean is it thread safe, Ruby wouldn't have a `Thread` function if it wasn't safe to thread with..?

Comment: I meant, when I read & update a local variable in multiple threads, shouldn't the result differ?

Comment: I wonder, how the order of applying atomic `succ` operation to `Integer` might affect the result?

Comment: @mudasobwa What do mean by applying `succ`?

Comment: [`Integer#succ`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Integer.html#method-i-succ) You increased an integer N times by one. How the order could matter?

Comment: It prints different values when I try.  I ran from Atom editor though, not IRB

Comment: @mudasobwa But incremented integer in 1000 threads, shouldn't they read  different values it everything is running concurrently?

Comment: @WandMaker It does print different values, but how does the final summation remain same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Huh!! Finally I found a way to prove, that it will not result `100000` always on irb.

Running following code gave me the idea,

```
100.times do
i = 0
1000.times do
Thread.start { 100.times { i += 1 } }
end
puts i
end
```

I see different values, most of the times. Mostly, it ranges from `91k to 100000`.

Answer (score 3):

No code is thread-safe automatically, you have to work to make it thread safe.

In particular the `+=` operation is actually three operations: read, increment, write. If these get mixed in with other threads you can have wildly unpredictable behaviour.

Consider the following series of events on two threads:

```
  A       B
-------------
READ
         READ
INCR
         INCR
WRITE
         WRITE
```

This is the simplest case where you'll have two increment operations yet since they both use the same original value one of them is nullified.

In my testing this is less likely to occur on a dual core system but practically a constant problem on four core machines simply because many behave like two loosely connected dual core systems, each with its own cache. It's even more pronounced when using [JRuby](http://jruby.org) where the threading support is much better. That example code you have yields random answers for me, anywhere from 98200 to 99500.

To make this thread safe you *must* employ a `Mutex` or use an atomic increment operation from a library like [Concurrent Ruby](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby) which will give you the tools to do this safely.

The alternative is to avoid mixing data between threads or use a structure like [`Queue`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Queue.html) to manage communication. No two threads should ever be manipulating the same object without a Mutex.

Comment: I understand Mutex & locking. But I don't see different results. I'm on lenovo E40, intel i5, I'm pretty sure it can run more than 4 threads simultaneously.

Comment: @Abhishek An i5 can schedule any number of threads, but only four will be actively executing at any given time. Even a single core machine can have threading race conditions if the scheduler kicks in at an inopportune time, like just after a read. You have no control over this *unless* you have Mutexes to ensure you have exclusive access to a particular piece of data.

Comment: Exactly! So, why do I see same output always?

Comment: It's a fluke, your code isn't thread safe but it works by pure chance. Try with Jruby. I'm never getting 100000 with that.

Comment: Okay. Let me try with `Jruby` & get back.

Comment: The default Ruby (MRI) only ever executes on one system thread at a time so the likelihood of these bugs appearing is significantly lower. Changing your code to do `100000.times` and `1000.times` yielded a count of 99671315 for me using Ruby 2.3.0 (MRI).

Comment: I tried adding another loop to print values, and it worked! Thanks for you time.

Comment: The GIL on MRI is probably muddying the water

Comment: Remember these sorts of things are highly variable, and probability weighs in heavily. Longer runs suffer more badly, so try and test more aggressively to prove your code doesn't (or does) work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

"*In computer science, a thread of execution is the smallest sequence of programmed instructions that can be managed independently by an operating system scheduler. A thread is a light-weight process.*"

```
irb(main):001:0> def calculate_sum(arr)
irb(main):002:1>   sleep(2)
irb(main):003:1>   sum = 0
irb(main):004:1>   arr.each do |item|
irb(main):005:2*     sum += item
irb(main):006:2>   end
irb(main):007:1>   sum
irb(main):008:1> end
=> :calculate_sum
irb(main):009:0>
irb(main):010:0* @items1 = [12, 34, 55]
=> [12, 34, 55]
irb(main):011:0> @items2 = [45, 90, 2]
=> [45, 90, 2]
irb(main):012:0> @items3 = [99, 22, 31]
=> [99, 22, 31]
irb(main):013:0>
irb(main):014:0* threads = (1..3).map do |i|
irb(main):015:1*   Thread.new(i) do |i|
irb(main):016:2*     items = instance_variable_get("@items#{i}")
irb(main):017:2>     puts "items#{i} = #{calculate_sum(items)}"
irb(main):018:2>   end
irb(main):019:1> end
=> [#<Thread:0x2158ab8@(irb):15 run>, #<Thread:0x2158860@(irb):15 run>, #<Thread:0x2158488@(irb):15 run>]
irb(main):020:0> threads.each {|t| t.join}
items3 = 152
items2 = 137
items1 = 101
=> [#<Thread:0x2158ab8@(irb):15 dead>, #<Thread:0x2158860@(irb):15 dead>, #<Thread:0x2158488@(irb):15 dead>]
irb(main):021:0>
```

This is a basic example of threading a process in Ruby. You have the main method `calculate_sum` that takes an array as an argument `@item1, @item2, @item3`. From there you make three threads `threads = (1..3)` map them into their own variable `.map do |i|` and start a new `Thread` instance with the variable that the thread was mapped to, `Thread.start(i)`.

From here you create an item variable that is equal to whatever the instance variable is `items = instance_variable_get(<object>)` output the result of the calculations, `puts "items#{<thread-variable>} = #{calculate_sum(items)}"`.

As you can see the threads begin to run simultaneously `=> [#<Thread:0x2158ab8@(irb):15 run>, #<Thread:0x2158860@(irb):15 run>, #<Thread:0x2158488@(irb):15 run>]`. The threads are all executed by calling each thread and joining them `threads.each {|t| t,join}`.

The last section is the most important, the threads are all run and die at the same time, however, if a thread has a very long process that thread must end before the program will end. Example:

```
irb(main):023:0> Thread.new do
irb(main):024:1*   puts t
irb(main):025:1>   Thread.new do
irb(main):026:2*     sleep(5)
irb(main):027:2>     puts h
irb(main):028:2>   end
irb(main):029:1> end
=> #<Thread:0x2d070f8@(irb):23 run>
irb(main):030:0> hello
goodbye
```

The second thread never exits, so it will keep running the process until you cut the execution.

In the main example the end has `=> [#<Thread:0x2158ab8@(irb):15 dead>, #<Thread:0x2158860@(irb):15 dead>, #<Thread:0x2158488@(irb):15 dead>]` because all the threads finish the process, and exit immediately. In order for my process to finish you would have to provide an `exit` for the second thread.

I hope this answers your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Ruby does not have an officially specified memory model like Java has since Java 5 or C++ has since C++11.

In fact, Ruby really does not have an official specification *at all*, although there have been multiple attempts at it, all of them have the same problem, that the designers of Ruby aren't actually using them. So, the only specification that Ruby has is basically "whatever YARV does". (And, for example the ISO Ruby Language Specification simply doesn't specify the `Thread` class, thus side-stepping the problem altogether.)

**BUT!!!** For concurrency, this is basically unusable, because YARV is incapable of running threads in parallel, so a lot of concurrency issues simply do not arise in YARV and so the core library doesn't protect against those issues! However, if we were to say that the concurrency semantics of Ruby are whatever YARV does, the question now becomes: is the fact that we can't have parallelism part of the semantics? Is the fact that the core libraries aren't protected part of the semantics?

That's a struggle that implementations like JRuby, Rubinius, IronRuby, MacRuby, etc., which have threads that can run in parallel, are facing. And they are still working on figuring out the answers.

So, the *tl;dr* answer to your question is: We don't know whether Ruby is thread-safe because we don't know what the threading semantics of Ruby are.

It's quite common for multi-threaded programs that work fine on YARV to break on JRuby, for example, but again, is it the program's fault or JRuby's? We can't tell because we don't have a specification that tells us what the multi-threaded behavior of a Ruby implementation should be. We could take the easy way out and say, well, Ruby is whatever YARV does, and when the program works on YARV, then we must change JRuby so that the program also works on YARV. However, parallelism is actually one of the main reasons why people choose JRuby in the first place, so this is simply not feasible.