# How to clearly present outputs from two concurrent threads

Tags: ruby, multithreading, screen, stdout

Sometimes it is straightforward to use threads in Ruby scripts, for example concurrent network queries can run parallel. In this case the output of the threads is printed to the screen one by one, and they are mixed together. Would be nice if each thread would have a separate area on the screen to print its output there. I think it is possible to achieve this, because cursor can be positioned on the screen. Does Ruby standard library contain any tools which help implement this shared screen?

Comment: A very easy solution I've often seen is that every Thread puts its id into the message. If you are interested in a specific thread, you can `grep` for it. But it isn't an shared screen. ;-)

Comment: Those are not so important messages, which I don't want to log into a file, I only would like to track the progress of the different threads, especially while testing / developing my scripts.

Comment: What I've done in similar cases is catching the stdout and stderr of all threads in seperate Strings (one per thread). Then, when execution has finished, output one string after the other (with big fat titles between them). Pro: Outputs separated. Contra: Output not visible until after execution.

Comment: Checkout this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997976/is-ruby-thread-safe-by-default/37998444#37998444

Comment: You could check out the [curses](https://github.com/ruby/curses) gem.

Comment: Make your threads write to different files, then open two consoles, tile them on your screen and `tail -f` from them. You can also use something like `screen` or `tmux`. (It helps if you are NOT a Windows user.) The bother of going the ncurses route seem to high for me, as you don't need this for production.

Comment: I created the github.com/puppetlabs/in-parallel gem, with solving this problem as one of the goals.  It forks processes rather than spawning threads, but the logic to handle the stdout would be very similar. It temporarily keeps all stdout in separate files in a /tmp directory and you could tail each file during execution. When a process completes, it outputs all of the stdout for that process to stdout at once and deletes the file.