# Mutual Exclusion not happened in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, mutual-exclusion

Program:

```
def inc(n)
    n + 1
end

sum = 0
threads = (1..10).map do
    Thread.new do
        10_000.times do
            sum = inc(sum)
        end
    end
end
threads.each(&:join)
p sum
```

Output:

```
$ ruby MutualExclusion.rb 
100000
$
```

My expected output of above program is less than 100,000. Because, the above program create 10 threads and each of the thread 
update the shared variable 'sum' to 10,000 times. But during execution of the program, mutual exclusion will definitely happen. Because,
mutual exclusion is not handled here. So I expect less than 100,000 as output. But it gives exactly 100,000 as output. How it is 
happened ? Who handle the mutual exclusion here ? And how I experiment this problem(ME).

Comment: Did you test your code in MRI or JRuby?

Comment: @spickermann No. I am a newbie. And I didn't aware of that.

Comment: @spickermann that said, MRI :)

Comment: There is a lot of overlap with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997976/is-ruby-thread-safe-by-default/38001872#38001872

Comment: not exactly the answer _why_, but you could get the race condition by adding some `Kernel.sleep` in `inc` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default interpreter for Ruby (MRI) doesn't execute threads in parallel. The mechanism that's preventing your race condition from introducing casually unexpected behavior is the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL).

You can learn more about this, including a very similar demonstration, here: http://www.jstorimer.com/blogs/workingwithcode/8085491-nobody-understands-the-gil

Comment: Just I got misgave. Do you think it is right. Because instead of properly handling the mutual exclusion, is it ok to completely set the property like `only one thread can execute Ruby code at any one time`. Due to this, the parallel execution of thread is avoided. This destroy the major use of thread. What do you think about this. It is pros or cons to ruby ?

Comment: @mrg Not necessarily; it depends on what you're doing. Especially when building web services, you're going to be doing a lot of IO (e.g. API requests); the thread-scheduler can pause while IO performs in the background, handling other requests in the meantime. For CPU-bound tasks, however, another interpreter is recommended (rbx / rubinius is quite good).

Comment: So shall I take MRI is good for web services and rbx is good for cpu-bound task ?

Comment: @mrg Only if you want to oversimplify. I encourage you to do some additional reading to develop a more nuanced understanding of the options.